# Increasing ID in controller to database

Tags: php, laravel

This how my id looks like `1-66-0001` on the first day of each day. Now, i want to know how i could increase the last 4 digits by 1. The next id should be `1-66-0002`, `1-66-0003` and display the just the last 4 digits in my html table (although the whole id ``1-66-0001` goes into the database) but with my code, i am not getting that.

**Controller**

```
if (!empty($invoice) && $invoice->created_at->toDateString() == $today->toDateString())
{
    $today_invoice = $invoice + 1;
} else {
    $today_invoice = $id . '-' . $date . '-0001';
}
```

Comment: Maintaining such a counter in your database sounds like a real pain to me.  Would you be open to an alternative of generating that ID at the time you query?  Given a date, we can construct the four digit ID, etc.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  Sure. How would i construct the four digit ID which is incremental ?

Comment: @XamarinDevil - I fixed your missing ; on $today_invoice = $invoice + 1

Comment: get last id and change thorugh string function.primary key is int so make an another field to save custom id

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, how is that?

Comment: Define a starting date where the ID is 1, then use the date difference in days as the offset from 1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, can you code sample to explain.?

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to use two "ID" fields: real id and id for database because I don't think it's good database design to use id as primary key with such length and format.
So: Id (PK): int(11)
    RealId (non-clustered index): varchar (10)

As it's string, using string formatting functions you can measure last id number and input it into database.

Also, if "0001" from real id and "1" from primary key are equal and will always be equal, i mean there is only one record with 0001, even without using string formatting functions, you can take primary key value and use it in your realId

if it's 20 -> you will know that last 4 digits should be 0020 and so on.

Comment: my realID has to reset each day. wouldn't there be a collision?

Comment: what do you mean under 'reset' ? 
If it's Monday today and realId is 1-66-0001
what it will be tomorrow ?

Comment: Tomorrow will 1-67-0001. This should help the user know the number of invoices created in the day.. `67` is the day of the year.

Comment: Tomorrow will 1-67-0001 -> this will be id of new record or we should update 1-66-0001 invoice`s value into 1-67-0001.